# Is it ever grammatically correct to say "I'm sure they're."

Tags: grammaticality

I currently can't think of a good reason grammatically; but there are plenty in terms of clear communication.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not correct. I'm assuming a conversation like:

> A : Are they working on the project?
>   B : I'm sure they are.

"Are" is an auxiliary verb. You're not saying they **are** (as in, they exist), you are saying they **are working**.

Because of the conversational structure, you don't need to repeat "working" as it is apparent since you're immediately answering a question.

However, you stress the "are" when you reply. Therefore, you can't contract it because you fully pronounce it.

> B : I'm sure they **are**
>   (you stress the last word)

If you want to contract the "are", you need to add "working" to the sentence.

> B : I'm sure they're **working**
>   (stressing the last word again)

**Note** It does sound weird if you repeat the "working". It's correct, but less fluent than saying "they are".

**Note** While you cannot contract the verb, you can still contract the negation:

> B : I'm sure they **are**n't
>   (stress on the bold letters)

**Afterthought** Come to think of it, when you negate, you can actually contract the verb, as you are now stressing the *negation* instead of the *verb*.

> B : I'm sure they're **not**
>   (stress on the bold letters)

Comment: IF you can pronounce/verbalize it, you can write it. Such short forms is not so much as grammatical but merely reflection of the actual elision of phonemes.